# show more than one comment per post or image

Tags: php, mysql

I've figured how to display a image with a comment from a user that post it but i can't display the rest of the comments. So is their a way to retrieve more than one comment froma table. Is their a way to do it in php or msysql. I've looked an and can't figure it out.

```
TABLE Header
 username
id
who
where

 Table images
message
name
 mid  - id that auto increments when image is loaded
id
 content

Table reply
 mid  id that is taken from images mid to relate image to reply.
 reply
 id ----this is only for an id for a reply that is auto increment
```

Table stucture is above

```
SELECT images.id, images.who, header.username, images.message, images.name, reply.reply
FROM header, images
LEFT JOIN reply ON reply.reply = reply.mid
OR reply.mid = images.mid
WHERE images.name IS NOT NULL = header.id
AND images.who IS NOT NULL 
AND images.message IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY images.mid
```

below is the html structure.

```
 <table>
     <tr>
         <td>
             <a href="a/<?=$name ?>" rel='lightbox' title='$timestamp - $message'> <img src=  "a/<?=$name ?>" width='150' height='100'" >  </a>
         </td> 
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><?=$row['name'] ?></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><?=$row['who'] ?></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><?=$row['message'] ?></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><?=$row['id'] ?></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><?=$row['mid'] ?></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><?=$row['username'] ?></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><?=$row['reply'] ?></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

If you need more clarification on the code or more code just ask.

Answer (score 0):

okay. I'm really disappointed that a lot of people could not get this simple answer. The answer is simple.

```
  SELECT images.name, GROUP_CONCAT(  'reply.reply'
   SEPARATOR  "|" ) 
   FROM images, reply
   WHERE reply.mid = images.mid
   OR reply.mid = reply.reply
    GROUP BY images.mid
```

Since I'm a nice person i leave this answer for people who will get stuck on such a simple problem. Thank me.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have syntax error. There is no syntax like `<?=` in php. The right syntax is `<?php`. To display a variable, you can use `<?php echo ... ?>`